# What is difference between Promise, await/async, and setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I understood the difference between Promise and await/asyc is error handling and readable code.
Promise can use .catch() for error handling, but async/await doesn't have a function to error handle, so we have to use try-catch(), and async/await is better when code becomes longer.

But I couldn't get the difference between setTimeout. What is the difference between three asynchronous functions?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. `async` and `await` are just syntactic sugar for working with promises but what exactly do you want to know about `setTimeout()` that [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) doesn't answer? I don't see what the two have to do with each other

Comment: `async-await` is syntactic sugar for promises; `async-await` syntax makes it easier to use promises.

Comment: Both promises and `setTimeout` are interfaces to the event loop to run callbacks when something happens. `setTimeout` only accepts one calback, and only responds to passing of time. Promises accept two types of callbacks (for success or failure) and can have many of them. Promises respond to whatever you tell them to.

Comment: I would also note that there's a difference between microtask and macrotask when comparing setTimeout with promises. Promises are run inside the microtask queue, but setTimeout is run inside the macrotask queue.

Comment: I agree with my question was not clear, and I understood setTimeout with the answer below and document! There is one more question. Is Promise better to handle errors than async-await?

Comment: _"Is Promise better to handle errors than async-await"_... both are different syntax for the same thing. Use whatever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With setTimeout you just set a time in milliseconds that the procedure should wait until the callback function inside the setTimeout call is getting called.

Meaning:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('Hello World!');
}, 1000);
```

When the setTimeout is getting executed, it will wait 1000 milliseconds = 1 second until it performs the console.log(); action.

In case of error handling, you still need to handle your errors manually, but you're also able to resolve Promises in the setTimeout.
So you could tell the program that it should wait 1 second until it resolves the Promise and it can catch exceptions as you said with the .catch() on the Promise call.

TL;DR: Async methods just wait until the method is done (if you await them) and setTimeout executes a code block after a given amount of milliseconds.

Comment: I would add that the timeout interval is a hint. It is not guaranteed that it will use that exact value. Actually the value is taken as a lower bound.

Comment: This is true! Even if you give him 0 or 1 millisecond; By default it will be 4ms by default from HTML5, but most browsers minimum is around 10ms ish.